# CakePHP fatal error: Class 'ErrorHandler' not found

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, error-handling

I've generated testsuits via "cake bake testsuit" and used localhost/test.php for my app.
So, the is an error when I tried to run one of test (else tests are valid):

`Fatal error: Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in Z:\home\prodvigator\www\cake\libs\object.php on line 201`

This models and controllers are generated by scaffold and I don't think that an error is in this sources.

Using:
CakePHP 1.3
The latest SimpleTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try checking the generated tests for an error that gets written at the top of the file.

sometimes i've been known to find something like this in both model and controller tests.

```
Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/New_York' for 'EDT/-4.0/DST' instead in /projectname/cake/console/templates/default/classes/test.ctp on line 22
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case, deleting all the files in the folder `/app/tmp/cache/persistent` solved the problem.

Comment: You saved my day! Spent an hour try to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in C:\[path]\core\cake\libs\object.php on line 211
( ! ) Error: Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in C:\[path]\core\cake\libs\object.php on line 211
```

The error was happening to me when trying to visit http://localhost/user_accounts/index

I already had the view created at app\views\user_accounts\index.ctp with the following content:

```
<div>
    Text from div
</div>
```

I had created the corresponding controller as well at app\controllers\user_accounts_controller.php:

```
<?php 
    class UserAccountsController extends AppController {
        public function index() {
            // Render the view in /views/user_accounts/index.ctp
            $this->render();
        }
    }
?>
```

Since I was not associating a model to this controller, I was missing this: `var $uses = array();`. It would have saved me time if the error had been more explicit, something such as "You do not have a model associated to this controller".

The fix was:

```
<?php 
    class UserAccountsController extends AppController {
        // Use this controller without a need for a corresponding Model file.
        var $uses = array();
        public function index() {
            // Render the view in /views/user_accounts/index.ctp
            $this->render();
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was thrown by a cronjob, that was calling a URL that didn't exist with php-cli instead of the main site.

The problem was irrelevant because the cronjob is not needed anymore, so but there still seems to be an error, that is only caused if called via console not via browser.

So check your error log if you call the site directly via the php command on the console to debug this further